# How to get values from one class use in another?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am really new to this, but I have 3 classes, and one of them uses the command line to ask the user to press 1 or 2 to answer questions, and then I am using a `get; set;` to collect that information in a different class.

I want to write that information into a text document. The problem is, my class where I am using `StreamWriter` isn't recognizing the words I used to define the information in the other class. Any help would be great. This is where I want the information to go.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dan\Documents\testText.txt");
writer.WriteLine("Passenger Information" //want the SeatSelection in here);
writer.Close();
```

The original information comes from here. Although in this code, it is recognizing the word "SeatSelection"? Why is it recognizing here but not above?

```
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Please select first or third class for your trip. ");
Console.WriteLine("1) First Class Compartment.");
Console.WriteLine("2) Third Class with Compartments.");
Console.WriteLine("3) Car C Open seating.");
Console.WriteLine("4) Car D Open seating.");
Console.WriteLine("5) Return to booking main menu.");
bool validInput = false;

do
{
    validInput = true;
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
    switch (key.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.D1:
        case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
            seatClass.SeatSelection = "First Class";
            FirstClass();
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.D2:
        case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
            seatClass.SeatSelection = "Third Class Compartment";
            ThirdClassCompartments();
             break;
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a reference to `seatClass`. It would be helpful if you showed all code, and that would include using directives, namespaces, class names, and method names in this case, including that information for your `Seat` class.

Comment: Is there any chance you could update your code, so that we can see your whole classes.  Basically you want to get the appropriate instance of the Seat class and then use that in WriteLine statement.

Comment: Don't change the question when your problem changes, ask a new question when the original isn't sufficient anymore. If you do change the question the answers aren't valid anymore, which doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your application structure is, but you want something along these lines:

```
var seatClass = UserInterface.GetSeatClass();

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dan\Documents\testText.txt");
writer.WriteLine("Passenger Information" + seatClass.SeatSelection);
writer.Close();
```

...where the I have creatively inserted an imaginery UserInterface static class that returns a new instance of a SeatClass from it's GetSeatClass method:

```
public static class UserInterface
{
    public static SeatClass GetSeatClass()
    {
        var seatClass = new SeatClass();

        //code here that assigns values to seatClass

        return seatClass;
    }
}
```

I can give you a better answer with more information.  Please don't hesitate to ask any questions.  (I'm sorry I've used a static class when you're just starting out.  I can explain if required.)

Comment: Okay I found something on the MSDN, and I managed to put something together that works, but now it is only writing one of the line to the text file? I will put the code for this in my question, its too long for this comment thing:

Comment: Excellent.  I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var filePath = @"C:\Users\Dan\Documents\testText.txt";
var lines = new[] {"a line content"};
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

Instead of StreamWriter stuff.

Comment: This is not an answer to his problem.

Comment: @StijnvanGaal problem in question is directly related with StreamWriter and simpler alternative is in this answer. So it can solve the problem in question. (If the problem is the fact that you are hungry and you can't eat meat, eating some other alternative solves your problem of hunger right?)